# Javascript prev/next buttons populated from database

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use javascript for next and previous buttons that cycle through a list of professors in a database. The code I have works except for one bizarre glitch: when there are over 9 professors (for this example there will be 11 professors), clicking the "previou"s button on Prof2 displays Prof1, Prof10, & Prof11 simultaneously.

Similarly, clicking "next" on the last prof, like Prof11 in this example, displays Prof1, Prof10, & Prof11 simultaneously. Can you spot the error? Is there a simpler way to create these buttons? Thank you in advance.

```
$.vars = {
counter : 2,
limit : $getUnitFacultyPages.TotalItems,

};

function nextItem() {
$('li','#profs')
.fadeOut('slow')
.filter( function() { return this.id.match('profs' + $.vars.counter); })
.fadeIn('slow');
$.vars.counter == $.vars.limit? $.vars.counter = 1 : $.vars.counter++; 
}

function prevItem() {
$.vars.counter -= 2;

if($.vars.counter == 1){ 
    $.vars.counter = $.vars.limit;
} else if ($.vars.counter < 0){
    $.vars.counter = $.vars.limit -1;
}

nextItem();
}

$("#profs-next").click(function () {
nextItem();
});

$("#profs-prev").click(function () {
prevItem();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that stands out is use of match that would "match" the regular expression and would cause the behavior that you describe. This should be changed the equality.

```
return this.id.match('profs' + $.vars.counter);
```

should be

```
return this.id == 'profs' + $.vars.counter;
```

There could be other things as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether or not this will solve your problem, but there are a couple things that look a little suspect to me at a glance:

1. Why do you decrement by 2?
2. You're checking if `$.vars.counter == 1` or `$.vars.counter < 0`. What happens if `$.vars.counter == 0`?

Edit:

Also, your prev/next logic is a little strange (imo). Ignoring your display logic, I might change it to:

```
$.vars = {
idx: 0,
limit: 5,
};

function nextItem()
{
    $.vars.idx = $.vars.idx >= $.vars.limit ? 0 : ++$.vars.idx;
}

function prevItem()
{
    $.vars.idx = $.vars.idx <= 0 ? $.vars.limit : --$.vars.idx;
}
```